# VS Code integration with C++ development-environment inside Docker

Tags: c++, docker, cmake, visual-studio-code

I would like to run VSCode on my host machine, but (using its features / extensions) fire up tools from within the dev-env living inside my Docker container.

I have set up a docker image as a development environment for C++. Let's call it `dev-env`.

It is linux-based and contains required libraries, crosscompilation toolchains and various tools we use for building and testing our software (cmake, ninja, cppcheck, clang-tidy etc.)

I have a GIT repository on a host machine, which I mount inside a docker. 
So my usual workflow would be to run docker:

```
host$
host$ docker run -v path/to/my/codebase/on/host:path/inside/docker -h dev-env --rm -it image_name bash
docker#
docker# cd build; cmake ..
 etc...
```

And as such, I can build, test and run my tools *inside* my unified development environment *inside* the docker.

Now, the goal is to take it out of the terminal to the world of IDE.
I happen to use VS Code.

On host machine, I open my codebase folder in VSCode. Since it's mapped inside the docker, any changes I make locally will be available inside `dev-env` as well.

But if I now run anything from VSCode (CMake configure, build, etc.) it will of course call the tools from within my host machine - which of course will not work, and is not what I want.

With tasks defined in `tasks.json` I could probably manage with having them run something like `docker exec CONTAINER my_command`

It gets more complicated with extensions:

What I would like is to have the e.g. *VSCode CMake Tools* extension configured in such a way, that when I run `Cmake Configure` (in a VSCode running on my host machine), it will actually run cmake commands from *within* Docker container, using cmake installed inside Docker, not from my host machine.

Temporary solution: Forwarding display through X / VNC

So Installing VSCode inside the Docker, running x/vnc server inside the Docker, exposing port and connecting to it from the host machine.

Yes, it is possible, I have it running here. But it has many limitations and problems, of which the most painful is the lag/delay. 
This is bad solution in general, so I would strongly push for avoiding this.

Another solution that I can think about:

VSCode instance running as a server inside the docker.
VSCode instance on your host connecting to the server instance.
You do all the work inside your host VSCode, but anytime you run a command, it is executed by a server instance, which runs everything inside Docker. 
I guess this would require support from VSCode (or maybe an extension).
VSCode [Live Share](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare-pack#overview) extension is not made exactly for that, but it's functionalities might do the job. I have not tested it yet.

Comment: [Visual Studio 2017 IDE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/linux/download-install-and-setup-the-linux-development-workload?view=vs-2017) (not code) has Linux remote development capabilities (via ssh/gdb). But works on Windows only I think.